# Resharper 10.0.2 does not apply naming style rules to method names

Tags: resharper, naming-conventions, resharper-10.0

Recently we found that Naming Styles on Resharper stop working on method names no sure why. On previous versions it worked for sure but we have no idea when it stopped working or if it is related with a version change (we moved to 10.0.2 several months ago).

Here is an example showing the issue:
[image]

Only the variable name is detected as wrong, not the method names. May be we activated a setting deactivating some checks or may it be a Resharper issue?

All layers have been reset before doing the test just to be sure that nothing else influences the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pretty similar request in [ReSharper bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-463980)